# how to enable radio button placed along with a drop down?

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I am adding a drop down along with a radio button list

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtnlInsertMistake" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                        ValidationGroup="insertMistake">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Text"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Image"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Table"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Missing Para"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMissingParaPosition" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 270px;
                        margin-top: -21px;">
                        <asp:ListItem>Up</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Below</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text="Description:" Style="margin-left: 8px;"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbxDescription" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3" Columns="38"
                        Style="margin-left: 8px; resize: none;">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

The problem is that radio button list is disable and only values in drop down can be changed. When i comment drop down the radio button list becomes enable.

I want to know that what is the problem with this code why radio button list become disable after adding drop down and how to resolve this issue.

Comment: How is it `Disabled`? Is it showing but you can't select anything?

Comment: yes radio button is showing but it can not be selected, options become freezed

Comment: One more question: is this your own code or someone else's? I mean is there anything in the project of which you may not be aware? Like some javascript code disabling the radio buttons?

Comment: yes this is mine own code and there is no javascript or jquery used in it.

Comment: In that case, can you show me the generated HTML source using `View Source` in your browser?